# Issue trying to use a class's name in it's own Class Variable section

Tags: python, class, pyqt, class-variables

I'm writing an app in Python and PyQt right now, and I've having a bit of an issue.  This problem doesn't require an knowledge of PyQt itself, just that of static variables in python. I'm tyring to add some signals to a class, which will emit the instance of the class when the signal is tripped.

What I have is something like this:

```
class Foo(QObject):
    # ...
    # Signals
    updated = pyqtSignal(Foo)
    moved = pyqtSignal(Foo)
    # ...
```

Python is giving me the error:

```
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

IIRC, this has to do something with when the class `Foo` is bound to the globals.  I also can't use `self` here either.  Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the statement `updated = pyqtSignal(Foo)` is evaluated *while `Foo` is being constructed*, so `Foo` doesn't exist when that statement is evaluated..  In the general case, you'd have to move it outside the class definition, although there may be some pyqt magic (e.g. using `QObject` rather than `Foo` as described in the other answer):

```
class Foo(...):
   ...

Foo.updated = pyqtSignal(Foo)
```

Comment: I thought about using `QObject` but I decided against it.  I'll give this a shot, but isn't it considered bad practice to assign class variables after the definition of a class?

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work because the signal will need to be defined in the class structure, not outside of it.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like this signal pass own class variable. From reference this [pyqt signal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). It possibly to use `QObject`. (not `Foo` but subclass is same)

Or, if your want to pass anything object, I think your can use `object`;

```
class Foo(QObject):
    updated = pyqtSignal(object)
    moved = pyqtSignal(object)
```

And your can specified what class should be emit it in pyqt connect signal.

Comment: I'll throw my weight behind this answer. I've used `pyqtSignal(object)` before to pass objects through signals. I haven't specifically done it to pass a reference to an instance of the class the signal is define it (like you want to) but I can't see why it would be any different from what I've done before.