# PyQt - Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I've realized when creating a class variable to hold a QWidget, it crashes complaining that there is no QApplication. I could break it down to do this minimal example.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ThumbContextMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThumbContextMenu, self).__init__()

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    menu = ThumbContextMenu()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

def main():     
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Commenting #menu will launch the application, or putting #menu as an instance variable won't crash too.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478488/issue-trying-to-use-a-classs-name-in-its-own-class-variable-section

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use delayed initialization? Something like this, maybe:

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    menu = None

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        if Example.menu is None:
            Example.menu = ThumbContextMenu()
```

The problem is that menu is class variable, so it is being initialized when Example definition is evaluated, i.e. before you call QApplication constructor.